# Where com base no valor de uma variável

Tags: sql-server

Estou trabalhando na migração de uma API para uma plataforma nova e isso inclui a migração das queries que antes estavam escritas diretamente no código para funções no banco de dados. Um dos problemas que venho enfrentando é que algumas verificações que fazíamos no código não estão disponíveis no SQL Server (ou eu desconheço como fazê-las).

Preciso colocar uma condição do `where` dependendo do valor de uma variável. Por exemplo:

```
DECLARE @var AS INT = 10;

SELECT * FROM TB_SQL
WHERE col1 = 'StackOverflow'
IF(@VAR = 1) THEN
BEGIN
AND col2 = @var
END
ELSE
BEGIN
-- não coloca condição nenhuma
END
```

Nesse caso, a condição `AND col2 = @var` só iria ser incluída na query caso o valor da @var fosse igual a 1.

Existe alguma maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: Do jeito que está fazendo `@var` sempre será `10`. De onde você puxa o valor para setar a `@var`?

Comment: Não dá pra colocar um `if` assim no `where`, você pode usar a função condicional `iif()` ou `case` por exemplo

Comment: @rbz esse foi apenas um exemplo que eu criei rapidamente pra não expor dados da empresa. O valor da `@var`, no caso, vem de uma requisição POST.

Comment: @RicardoPontual usando o `iif()` eu consigo fazer isso dentro de uma `function`?

Comment: não entendi bem, você diz usar `iif` dentro de uma function, ou usar usa function dentro do `iif` ?

Comment: Usar o `iif` dentro de uma `function`. Mas, baseado na sua resposta abaixo, eu creio que consegui resolver meu problema. Vou apenas fazer mais alguns testes para ver se está resolvido mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com a função condicional [IIF()](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) você pode testar um valor e fazer a comparação do campo com a variável ou ela mesma, o que na prática ignora a condição:

```
DECLARE @var AS INT = 10;

SELECT * FROM TB_SQL
WHERE col1 = 'StackOverflow'
  AND col2 = IIF(@VAR = 1, @VAR, col2)
```

Se @VAR for igual a 1, compara ela com col2, senão compara col2 com col2, ou seja, ignora a condição pois sempre vai ser vardade

Comment: Esse `iif()`, além de facilitar a leitura do código, resolveu meu problema. Obrigado!